# Chrome Extension Statistics

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I released a chrome extension roughly ten hours ago and many people have downloaded it from what my friends have told me. For some reason, the statistics in the developer dashboard for the extension still say that there were 0 downloads, reviews, and ratings. Did I do something wrong or is Chrome's analytics really slow? If the latter, when can I expect for the statistics to be updated?

Comment: They probably update it once a day.

Comment: Interesting, but considering it's a Google product, I'd expect it to be much faster.

Comment: Google products can have outdated stuff here and there. It's nothing out of the ordinary, really.

Comment: True. I'm just being a bit impatient I guess plus thinking too high of Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a bit slow. It updates on a daily basis as @wOxxOm suggested.